# How to perform scheduling using python?

Tags: python, docker, cron

I am trying to schedule a few jobs inside my python. Supposely , the text from the logging should appear every 1 minute and every 5 minute from jobs.py file inside my docker container. However, the text is appearing every 2minutes inside the docker container. Is there a clash between the python schedule and cronjobs ?

Current Output inside the docker container

```
13:05:00 [I] werkzeug 172.20.0.2 - - [08/May/2022 13:05:00] "GET /reminder/send_reminders HTTP/1.1" 200 -

13:06:00 [I] werkzeug 172.20.0.2 - - [08/May/2022 13:06:00] "GET /feeds/update_feeds HTTP/1.1" 200 -

13:07:00 [D] schedule Running job Job(interval=1, unit=minutes, do=job_feeds_update, args=(), kwargs={})

13:07:00 [I] jobs job_feeds_update

13:07:00 [I] werkzeug 172.20.0.2 - - [08/May/2022 13:07:00] "GET /feeds/update_feeds HTTP/1.1" 200 -

13:08:00 [I] werkzeug 172.20.0.2 - - [08/May/2022 13:08:00] "GET /feeds/update_feeds HTTP/1.1" 200 -

13:09:00 [D] schedule Running job Job(interval=1, unit=minutes, do=job_feeds_update, args=(), kwargs={})

13:09:00 [I] jobs job_feeds_update

13:09:00 [I] werkzeug 172.20.0.2 - - [08/May/2022 13:09:00] "GET /feeds/update_feeds HTTP/1.1" 200 -

13:10:00 [I] werkzeug 172.20.0.2 - - [08/May/2022 13:10:00] "GET /feeds/update_feeds HTTP/1.1" 200 -

13:10:00 [I] werkzeug 172.20.0.2 - - [08/May/2022 13:10:00] "GET /reminder/send_reminders HTTP/1.1" 200 -

13:11:00 [D] schedule Running job Job(interval=1, unit=minutes, do=job_feeds_update, args=(), kwargs={})

13:11:00 [I] jobs job_feeds_update

13:11:00 [D] schedule Running job Job(interval=5, unit=minutes, do=job_send_reminders, args=(), kwargs={})

13:11:00 [I] jobs job_send_reminders
```

**server.py**

```
#Cron Job
@app.route('/feeds/update_feeds')
def update_feeds():
    schedule.run_pending()
    return 'OK UPDATED FEED!'
   
@app.route('/reminder/send_reminders')
def send_reminders():
    schedule.run_pending()
    return 'OK UPDATED STATUS!'
```

**jobs.py**

```
def job_feeds_update():
    update_feed()
    update_feed_eng()
    logger.info("job_feeds_update")
        
schedule.every(1).minutes.do(job_feeds_update)

# send email reminders
def job_send_reminders():
    send_reminders()
    logger.info("job_send_reminders")
schedule.every(5).minutes.do(job_send_reminders)
```

**Docker File**

```
FROM alpine:latest

# Install curlt 
RUN apk add --no-cache curl

# Copy Scripts to Docker Image
COPY reminders.sh /usr/local/bin/reminders.sh
COPY feeds.sh /usr/local/bin/feeds.sh

RUN echo ' */5  *  *  *  * /usr/local/bin/reminders.sh' >> /etc/crontabs/root
RUN echo ' *  *  *  *  * /usr/local/bin/feeds.sh' >> /etc/crontabs/root

# Run crond  -f for Foreground 
CMD ["/usr/sbin/crond", "-f"]
```

Comment: if anyone could help me , i would be appreciate it !

Comment: Does the reminders one just trigger '/reminder/send_reminders' and the feeds one trigger '/feeds/update_feeds' ? Also when does jobs.py get executed?

Comment: @Azaro yes it triggers the routes respectively

Comment: Gotcha - when does jobs.py get executed/initialized btw?

Comment: do u mean when does jobs.py run inside the docker container?

Comment: Yeah - is there a separate dockerfile for that? Just curious - i don't think there's anything wrong with it atm.

Also, to help us get more info, can you add `logger.info("job_feeds_update started")` to the top of your `job_feeds_update()` method (and do similar for the reminders job method log) just so that we can get a clear timestamp of when the jobs actually execute as well!

Comment: So i had two folders in my projects. I created a dockerfile for apps directory, job.py is inside apps directory and a dockerfile for cronjob directory. I am currently using docker compose to run two services for my projects. Okay , i will add the logger info and repost the latest timestamp.

Comment: Sounds good thanks. I suspect the issue might have to do with `schedule` not taking into account how long each job takes, and thus throws the scheduling out of sync.

Comment: i added `logger.info("job_feeds_updated started ")` to the top of  `job_feeds_update()` but it did not show the output of it.

Comment: is the output no issue ? it seems like the scheduling is not in sync, so i am wondering if its wrong or correct

Comment: It's odd to me that the "started" log doesnt print but the other log prints at the end of the function. But in any case I have some thoughts on what a potential issue might be. Trying to test things locally but give me a bit!

Comment: Alright !! look forward to hearing from you.

Comment: I posted a (lengthy) explanation. I have some suggestions on how you can solve your issue but I haven't added them to the post yet. I figured you could read the explanation while I continue editing my post with Solutions

Comment: Added a couple of possible solutions as well. Note, this will take some trial/error on your part to make sure everything is working as expected when you're testing the whole setup!

Comment: i will be reading it and take some time to process the information. I will update to you for the trial/error part to make sure it works everything

Comment: Great, hope it ends up helping!

Comment: thank you for spending the time and describe everything in details .  I will get back to you if i face any problems during the implementation

Comment: No problem! Note, I just added an extra possible solution I just found out about: https://pypi.org/project/ischedule/ `ischedule` module that works like schedule but actually takes into account the job execution time. This may be the simplest solution for you to get things running if the queues/threads are too much!

Comment: Just wanted to follow up and see if it ended up helping!

Comment: @Azarro using ischedule helps to maintain a consistent job execution time and scheduling. thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're running into a couple of issues:

1. As you suspected, your `schedule` is on a different schedule/interval than your cron job. They're out of sync (and you can't ever expect them to be in sync for the next reason). From the moment your `jobs.py` script was executed, that's the starting point from which the schedule counts the intervals.

i.e. if you're running something every minute but the `jobs.py` script starts at 30 seconds into the current minute (i.e. 01:00:30 - 1:00am 30 seconds past), then the scheduler will run the job at 1:01:30, then 1:02:30, then 1:03:30 and so on.

2. `Schedule` [doesn't guarantee you precise](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) frequency execution. When the scheduler runs a job, the job execution time is not taken into account. So if you schedule something like your feeds/reminders jobs, it could take a little bit to process. Once it's finished running, the scheduler decides that the next job will only run 1 minute **after the end of the previous job**. This means your execution time can throw off the schedule.

Try running this example in a python script to see what I'm talking about

```
# Schedule Library imported
import schedule
import time
from datetime import datetime
     
def geeks():
    now = datetime.now() # current date and time
    date_time = now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
    time.sleep(5)
    print(date_time + "- Look at the timestamp")
 
geeks();
# Task scheduling
# After every 10mins geeks() is called.
schedule.every(1).seconds.do(geeks)
 
# Loop so that the scheduling task
# keeps on running all time.
while True:
 
    # Checks whether a scheduled task
    # is pending to run or not
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

We've scheduled the `geeks` function to run every second. But if you look at the geeks function, I've added a `time.sleep(5)` to pretend that there may be some blocking API call here that can take 5 seconds. Then observe the timestamps logged - you'll notice they're not always consistent with the schedule we originally wanted!

**Now onto how your cron job and scheduler are out of sync**

Look at the following logs:

```
13:07:00 [D] schedule Running job Job(interval=1, unit=minutes, do=job_feeds_update, args=(), kwargs={})
13:07:00 [I] jobs job_feeds_update
13:07:00 [I] werkzeug 172.20.0.2 - - [08/May/2022 13:07:00] "GET /feeds/update_feeds HTTP/1.1" 200 -

# minute 8 doesn't trigger the schedule for feeds

13:09:00 [D] schedule Running job Job(interval=1, unit=minutes, do=job_feeds_update, args=(), kwargs={})
13:09:00 [I] jobs job_feeds_update
13:09:00 [I] werkzeug 172.20.0.2 - - [08/May/2022 13:09:00] "GET /feeds/update_feeds HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

What's likely happening here is as follows:

- at 13:07:00, your cron sends the request to feed items
- at 13:07:00, the job schedule has a pending job for feed items
- at 13:07:00:, the job finishes and schedule decides the next job can only run after 1 minute from now, which is roughly ~13:08:01 (note the 01, this is to account for milliseconds/timing of job executions, which lets assume it took 1 second to run the feed items update)
- at 13:08:00, your cron job triggers the request asking `schedule` run_pending jobs.
- at 13:08:00 **however**, there are **no pending jobs to run** because the next time feed items can run is **13:08:01** which is not right now.
- at 13:09:00, your cron tab triggers the request again
- at 13:09:00, there is a pending job available that should've run at **13:08:01** so that gets executed now.

I hope this illustrates the issue you're running into being out of sync between cron and schedule. This issue will become worse in a production environment. You can read more about [Parallel execution](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parallel-execution.html) for `schedule` as a means to keep things off the main thread but that will only go so far. Let's talk about...

### Possible Solutions

1. **Use `run_all` from schedule** instead of `run_pending` to force jobs to trigger, regardless of when they're actually scheduled for.

But if you think about it, this is no different than simply calling `job_feeds_update` straight from your API route itself. This isn't a bad idea by itself but it's still not super clean as it will block the main thread of your API server until the `job_feeds_update` is complete, which might not be ideal if you have other routes that users need.

You could combine this with the next suggestion:

2. **Use a jobqueue and threads**
   Check out the second example on the [Parallel Execution page](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parallel-execution.html) of schedule's docs. It shows you how to use a jobqueue and threads to offload jobs.

Because you run `schedule.run_pending()`, your main thread in your server is blocked until the jobs run. By using threads (+ the job queue), you can keep scheduling jobs in the queue + avoid blocking the main server with your jobs. This should optimize things a little bit further for you by letting jobs continue to be scheduled.

3. **Use `ischedule` instead** as it takes into account the job execution time and provides precise schedules: https://pypi.org/project/ischedule/. This might be the **simplest solution** for you in case 1+2 end up being a headache!
4. **Don't use schedule** and simply have your cron jobs hit a route that just runs the actual function (so basically counter to the advice of using 1+2 above). Problem with this is that if your functions take longer than a minute to run for feed updates, you may have multiple overlapping cron jobs running at the same time doing feed updates. So I'd recommend not doing this and relying on a mechanism to queue/schedule your requests with threads and jobs. Only mentioning this as a potential scenario of what else you could do.